# LUA script on gaming mouse doesnt work in Origin software

Tags: lua, scripting, mouse, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Even though my Lua scripts for my gaming mouse Logitech G502 Hero work fine in Windows desktop, or every application or game I tries, they dont work on Battlefield and the Origin app.
Custom macros work, but the scripting doesnt.

Any ideas? or anyone else having the same problem?

Thanks! Emmanouil Filippou

Here is an example of a simple Lua script that I have tried and doesnt work.

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
            repeat  
                if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                    repeat
                        MoveMouseRelative(0,5)
                        Sleep(33)
                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
                end             
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
        end     
end
```

Comment: please contact Origin / Logitech support for issues like this

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to insert `Sleep`

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    Sleep(20)
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
        repeat  
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                repeat
                    MoveMouseRelative(0,5)
                    Sleep(33)
                until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
            end             
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
    end     
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesnt work in Origin software, it works in windows desktop or any other application, like it was working without this sleep. The problem is that the script is not working at all in Origin software only. 
So when I am in desktop, and I hold both left and right mouse, the cursor moves down continuously, in Origin software nothing happens like the Lua script is blocked somehow or doesnt exist

Comment: Sorry, I never used Origin. Is it just an app to help you buy and download games?  Do you really need anti-recoil macro working in it?  Please note that "Logitech Gaming Software" is compatible only with "gaming series" of Logitech devices and designed for working with games.

Comment: Thanks Egor, It doesnt work in Battlefield, Origin is where Battlefield is launched from, the script doesnt even work there... I wonder if anyone was able to run Lua scripts on Logitech mouse on Battlefield or any other Origin games...
I was originally using the LG Hub which is the new Logitech Gaming Software, and it didnt work there either, so I switched to Logitech Gaming Software which is supposed to be more flexible (you can import scripts). My mouse is Logitech G502 Hero Gaming Mouse, so it should work...
By the way, Logitech support says I need to contact Battlefield support!!

Comment: LGS/GHUB must work in Battlefield.  `Logitech support says I need to contact Battlefield support!` Hah, nice ping-pong! :-)

Answer (score 0):

also you need to launch G-Hub as administrator

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).